# UIPageControl allowsContinuousInteraction

Tags: ios, uikit, ios14

UIPageControl has a new way of changing a page, it's called continuous interaction, which is available in UIKit 14 and above.

I would like to know, if this behavior will be enabled in apps compiled against SDK 13 but launched on devices with iOS14 (after update from iOS 13)

**Updated:**

I don't have a device which I can update to iOS14

**Updated:**

I have Xcode 12. But the simulator is under iOS14 and I have to recompile the app, sdk 14 will be used, to install it on iOS14 simulator
I want to simulate a case when a user open, an app compiled with sdk13, on his devices after updating to iOS14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have Xcode 12. But the simulator is under iOS14 and I have to recompile the app, sdk 14 will be used, to install it on iOS14 simulator I want to simulate a case when a user open, an app compiled with sdk13, on his devices after updating to iOS14

You're doing it wrong. Build the app with Xcode 11 and locate the built app in the Finder. Switch to the Xcode 12 Simulator running iOS 14 and drag that app onto it. The app runs and now you can see how it behaves.

Alternatively, you can use Xcode 11 directly with an iOS 14 simulator. See https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/418/ starting at minute 12:28 for instructions.

[And the answer is... No, an iOS 13 app running on iOS 14 doesn't have continuous interaction enabled. It behaves like iOS 13.]

Comment: I appreciate your update. Question, does it mean that iOS comes with multiple versions of UIKit and other libraries? if not how they achieve it on the framework level that old apps behaves like they behaved on SDK which was used to compile an app?